# excel with vbscript which is using third party COM ADD-IN

Tags: excel, vbscript

I want to automate a process in excel with vbscript which is using third party COM ADD-IN

```
Sub LoadAddIn()
Dim oComAddIn As COMAddIn
Set oComAddIn = Application.COMAddIns.Item("C:\Program Files (x86)\Thomson Reuters\Eikon\EikonOfficeShim.dll")
oComAddIn.Connect = True

CreateFolder

End Sub
```

But while running excel from vbscript, it is opening without any add-ins enabled and formula which is using the above add-in are not working.

I googled so many websites but not getting exact syntax to use to connect third party add-in while executing excel from vbscript.

Comment: did you finally mange to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I can open the EIKON AddIn and start the process using the following:

```
'Start EIKON Update
Dim RetVal As Long
RetVal = ExecCmd("C:\Program Files (x86)\Thomson Reuters\Eikon\eikon.exe -officeexcel -a " & sPath)
```

Note that sPath is the full string path of the file I am opening.

Caveat: The file does not automatically close. I'm still working on that part.